# How to route url in flaskappbuilder?

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

I'm following this [Flaskappbuilder example](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/tree/master/examples/simpleview2). However when I want to route to a different url, e.g. for `method3` in `views.py`, if I want to route to `/method3/jonh` instead of `myview/method3/jonh`, it will return error: `the requested url was not found on the server. if you entered the url manually please check your spelling and try again.` I don't understand why do we need `myview`? And how can I route to a different url than the example?

In `views.py`, I changed `appbuilder.add_link("Method3", href='/myview/method3/jonh', category='My View')` to `appbuilder.add_link("Method3", href='/method3/jonh', category='My View')`. And if you change it to any other, like `appbuilder.add_link("Method3", href='/myview1/method3/jonh'`, same error will occur.

Comment: please post the smallest example of code you can to demonstrate your issue ... if you are using blueprints then that often has a required prefix that is included ...

Comment: I imagine you just change `appbuilder.add_link("Method2", href='/myview/method2/jonh', category='My View')` to `appbuilder.add_link("Method2", href='/method2/jonh', category='My View')`